Copy a ML Model from one Azure Databricks workspace to another Databricks Workspace
I ran the below code to export the ML Model in Azure Databricks based mlflow but I seem to be getting this error

MLflow host or token is not configured correctly

I'm unable to figure out what the issue is. The URL for the workspace is correct along with the PAT Token.
The export_import tools is very buggy. It expects mlfow library but what comes with Databricks ML Runtime is mlflow-skinny.
import mlflow
import os
from mlflow_export_import.model.export_model import ModelExporter
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

# Set the Databricks MLflow tracking URI with the workspace URL
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("https://adb-xxxyyymmmnnnyyy.1.azuredatabricks.net/")

# Set both tokens for compatibility
os.environ["DATABRICKS_TOKEN"] = "mnop6672ec8e20c7d219eb2A-3"
os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN"] = "mnop6672ec8e20c7d219eb2A-3"

# Initialize the MLflow client (no need to pass tracking URI as it's set globally)
mlflow_client = MlflowClient()

# Initialize the ModelExporter with the MLflow client
exporter = ModelExporter(mlflow_client)

# Export the model
exporter.export_model(
    model_name="Signature_Test",
    output_dir="/tmp/mlflow_export/model",
    stages=None,  # Use "None" to export all stages, or specify "Staging" or "Production"
    export_metadata_tags=True
)


Does below solution work for you?

when you install mlflow-export-import in libraries tab using PyPi option you get these errors because of bugs in the package installed via PyPi it is mentioned here document also you can check the limitations here , but still it exports the model with errors when using below code and adding library in cluster like below.

Code
from mlflow_export_import.model.export_model import ModelExporter
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
import os
mlflow_client = MlflowClient()

os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI"]="https://adb-112347890.10.azuredatabricks.net/"
os.environ["DATABRICKS_TOKEN"]="dapiexxxxxxxxxxxxx7b3d13cd155-3"

exporter = ModelExporter(mlflow_client)

exporter.export_model(
    model_name="RandomForestDiabetesModel",
    output_dir="/tmp/mlflow_exports/diabetes_rf"
)

But sometimes it creates bug and error to avoid it you use the bash command to export
Below is the code.
%sh 
export DATABRICKS_HOST=https://ad1384282929690.10.azuredatabricks.net
export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=dapixxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyycd155-3
export-model --output-dir /tmp/diabmodels/ --model RandomForestDiabetesModel

Output
Wed Oct  9 04:54:52 2024 Connection to spark from PID  9626
Wed Oct  9 04:54:52 2024 Initialized gateway on port 37871
Wed Oct  9 04:54:52 2024 Connected to spark.
MLflow Version: 2.16.2
MLflow Tracking URI: databricks
Options:
  model: RandomForestDiabetesModel
  output_dir: /tmp/diabmodels/
  notebook_formats: 
  stages: None
  versions: None
  export_latest_versions: False
Databricks REST client: https://adb-1004898840459690.10.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0
Found 1 'all' versions for model 'RandomForestDiabetesModel'
Exporting model 'RandomForestDiabetesModel' version 1 stage 'None' to '/tmp/diabmodels/d33df583d9214485a9793a9112b785fd'

Downloading artifacts:   0%|          | 0/11 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Downloading artifacts:   9%|▉         | 1/11 [00:00<00:00, 16194.22it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  18%|█▊        | 2/11 [00:00<00:01,  6.24it/s]   
Downloading artifacts:  18%|█▊        | 2/11 [00:00<00:01,  6.24it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  27%|██▋       | 3/11 [00:00<00:01,  6.24it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  36%|███▋      | 4/11 [00:00<00:01,  6.24it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  45%|████▌     | 5/11 [00:00<00:00,  6.24it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  55%|█████▍    | 6/11 [00:00<00:00,  6.24it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  64%|██████▎   | 7/11 [00:00<00:00,  7.62it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  64%|██████▎   | 7/11 [00:00<00:00,  7.62it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  73%|███████▎  | 8/11 [00:00<00:00,  7.62it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  82%|████████▏ | 9/11 [00:01<00:00,  6.29it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  82%|████████▏ | 9/11 [00:01<00:00,  6.29it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  91%|█████████ | 10/11 [00:01<00:00,  5.93it/s]
Downloading artifacts:  91%|█████████ | 10/11 [00:01<00:00,  5.93it/s]
Downloading artifacts: 100%|██████████| 11/11 [00:01<00:00,  6.13it/s]
Downloading artifacts: 100%|██████████| 11/11 [00:01<00:00,  6.13it/s]
Downloading artifacts: 100%|██████████| 11/11 [00:01<00:00,  6.35it/s]
Exported 1/1 'all' versions for model 'RandomForestDiabetesModel'

and model artifacts.


Hi Jayashankar, in the future, can you please use the built-in image uploader in the post editor so that images are uploaded to the Stack Overflow domain (i.sstatic.net) rather than uploading posts on a 3rd party site like Imgur? This helps prevent linkrot and allows users who can't access Imgur (e.g. from work locations that might block it) to view the images.

Sure, will do it
